# SSRS 2008R2 SQL Service Account Connection Issue

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2, service-accounts, spn

In our SSRS report manager page we get the below error on the Datasources. This all worked fine previously and seems to suddenly have stopped working. I have no idea what the issue could be.

All SPN are set up and the rsreportserver config file contains correct authentication...

```
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
        <RSWindowsKerberos/>
        <RSWindowsNTLM/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
```

[image]

In the SQL Server logs I see this error...

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error.
```

I followed the checklist listed here for SPN - http://blogs.technet.com/b/taraj/archive/2009/01/29/checklist-for-double-hop-issues-iis-and-sql-server.aspx but still not fixed the issue.

What is causing this issue??

Comment: Looks like the SQL Server service was running as 'Local System' rather than the service account. I changed this and works now!

So it seems that the SQL Service defaulted to run as 'Local System' when it restarted. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: I would likely say someone changed it. It would not happen on its own.